# bases and high frequencies in image

Tags: signal-processing, matlab

***Hi ,To detect bases and high frequencies with matlab i would like  to put 25% of image pixels to 0 like in the pictures ,someone have any idea how can i do it***

thank you

![put in zero the  center pixels][1]

![put in zero the border pixels   ][2]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an image `img` of 100x80 and you want the middle 25% to be set to zero, here is how you can do it:

```
img(26:75,21:60) = 0;
```

It should not be too hard to generalize this.

You may also be interested in setting them to `NaN` rather than to 0, just try it.